# Every open set in a separable space $X$ contains infinitely many points from the countable dense subset of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that if $X$ is a separable space, and $\{z_{n}\}$ is its countable dense subset, then every open subset of $X$ contains infinitely points from $\{z_{n}\}$. Is the following correct?

Consider an arbitrary open subset $Y \subset X$. Choose an arbitrary point in it, $z$. By the openness of $Y$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(z)$ is wholly contained in $Y$. Also, by the separableness of $X$, $B_{\frac{\epsilon}{j}}(z)$ must contain at least one point from $\{z_{n}\}$, for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Cleary, this implies that $B_{\epsilon}(z)$, and so $Y$, contains infinitely many points from $\{z_{n}\}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you working in a topological space or in a metric space?  You need to specify this up front.  Otherwise using ball doesn't make sense in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct. For different values of $j$ you may get the same point of $(z_n)$ so there is no guarantee that you get infinitely many points of $(z_n)$.

The result is not even true.

Consider $\mathbb N$  with the (usual) discrete metric. $\mathbb N$ is itself a countable dense set and $\{1\}$ is an open set. It contains only one point from the countable dense set $\mathbb N$.